# What are the reason when a stopped windows service starts automatically?

Tags: windows, service, windows-services

What are the reason when a stopped windows service starts automatically?

I know only few which are

1. When service start-up mode is automatic and someone re-start the server then service will also get started.
2. When someone forcefully start the service manually.

Is there any other way when a stopped service can start?

Answer (score 2):

[Service triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-trigger-events). This can be hardware device added, internet connection discovered, group policy change or any ETW event.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked there is a service Dependence? If another service depends on its function, it will automatically come up even though you stop the service.

Since it keeps restarting, it means you are not suppose to disable or stop the service.

Locate the ASP.NET State Service and check the Startup Type property and click the recovery tab for your service configuration and check if the options there could be restarting it.

You can also run a virus scan on your system to be sure your pc is safe.